# High Voltage Generation With PWM

Tags: transformer, circuit-design, pwm, high-voltage, flyback

I am trying to design 20W output power supply with about 1KV output with 20mA current. Designs I am working on are, 
1: [image]

But with this configuration ampere comes from the 12V DC supply goes too high like 10A. Even with this ampere I can't achieve 1KV. What kind of modifications should I make? Is this kind of design suitable for this?

Second design I am thinking something like :

[image]

But I didn't worked much on power supply designs. The design should be small as much as possible. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. But with this configuration ampere comes from the 12V DC supply goes too high like 10A. Even with this ampere I can't achieve 1KV.
>      What kind of modifications should I make? Is this kind of design
>      suitable for this?

Looking at the inductors in the transformer you have primary at 1 uH and secondary at 100 uH. Given that the coupled inductor ratio is 1:100, this implies a turns ratio of 1:10. So, if your primary voltage could be coerced into a voltage level of 20 volts p-p, the output would only be 200 volts p-p.

You don't have any snubber on the transformer primary and this sort of circuit could easily damage the MOSFET driver. You should aslo consider applying some form of feedback to ensure that (when you do fix the transformer ratio and have a snubber) it won't over-produce an excessive output voltage; call it load protection.

> 2. Second design I am thinking something like

Concentrate on design 1 is my advice. 1000 volts and 20 mA is only 20 watts and is suitable for design 1. However, you need to be much clearer about what your output requirements are: -

- DC or AC
- If AC what frequency and range
- Accuracy of output
- Regulation of output with loads.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Actually I didn't add snubber because right now I am just testing it.To improve output voltage 1kV I need about 1:500 inductor ratio. When I do this ampere on first winding goes up to 9A. Should I need 12V 9A DC supply then? And do you think if I do this can I achieve 20W output ? Thanks again. It helped me a lot.( btw AC or DC not much important for me)

Comment: If you can get 20 volts p-p on the primary then to get 1000 volts p-p on the secondary you'd need a ratio of 1:2500. It's quite possible that your transformer and operating frequency are unsuitable.

Comment: 1:2500 ? isn't it too much? With 5:500 inductance ratio right now I achieved ~1000V. Sorry asking too much, My main Problem is the ampere on primary. Is it possible to reduce it?

Comment: You will be suffering from excessive flyback problems and significantly overdriving your MOSFET (possible reason for the high DC current) with such a low turns ratio. Please, address what I've raised in my answer. This is a Q and A site and not an on-line school.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will try for snubber and other modifications:)

Comment: Good luck and consider altering your 555 timer to have the ability to generate less than 50% duty cycles because, with a light load on your HV you will need to have some form of regulation circuit to prevent that voltage from rising too high. The transformer and operating frequency will play a vital role i.e. using a standard mains transformer and trying to run it at (say or higher than) 1 kHz will be really problematic.